# time delay adjustment on Rheem elect furnace

Tags: hvac

Upon a call for heat the blower motor starts too soon resulting in cool to cold air coming out of the ceiling registers until heat strips start heating up.Wires coming from thermostat connect to curcuit board first then wires connect to the two sequencers.Time delay looks like it is solely controlled via ckt board. How do I adjust for a longer delay on motor start up? Furnace is a RHEEM model#RHLL-HM6024JA (07/2010) blower motor= 3/4hp X-13 CKT BRD is an EMERSON 4632E.(I have been in the a/c & heat trade off and on for 35yrs,with commercial refrigeration service making up 19yrs of it, I haven't been very active the past 10yrs so im a little rusty.

Comment: I really don't want to run Stat wires through a sequencer before they go to the board.

Comment: Is there a schematic on the inside of the unit? If so, can you post a clear photo of it? A clear photo of the control board, might also be useful.

Comment: The furnace probably is probably set up to detect the fan is running and up to speed before turning on the strips as a safety requirement.  If you try to make changes to the internal wiring, and the strips come on without air moving to cool them, you're not going to have a good time.  The strips probably turn off before the fan as well so they cool properly.

Comment: The board has no means of adjustment, no jumpers, no slots to knotch, no nothing! I'm thinking why not let stat energise the sequencers for the strips along with another sequencer to send the 24v to the board, that way the board gets power after strips.